# Photo viewing app to use for viewing comics which stays zoomed in between photos

Tags: image-viewer

I have a number of comics I can read that are saved as individual numbered pictures in a folder.  All I need to do is to cycle to the next photo to get the next page.

My main problem is that, depending on which comic I've downloaded, the comics may be so long that when auto-scaled to my monitor they are shrunk down to a size too small to allow me to read the text in word bubbles.  This forces me to either sit right on top of my monitor and squint to read or constantly zoom in, and then scroll down; which I would be fine with if I didn't have to zoom in on every single page.

Thus I'm looking for any photo viewing app which support a few features to make navigating a comic I need to zoom into more convenient.

1. Once I zoom in to a comic it will stay at that zoom ratio when I cycle between pages/images in a folder, rather then scaling back to the smaller auto-zoom size for each new page.
2. Allow me to scroll up and down a zoomed in page conveniently using the scroll wheel of my mouse; and start at the top of the zoomed in image every time I go to a new image.
3. allow forward and backwards cycling of photos in the folder.  Ideally allowing me to cycle photos using the 'forward' and 'back' buttons (ie button 4 & button 5) on my 5 button mouse.

Comment: Example of comic files?

Answer (score 1):

Quivi is an open source image viewer, available on [Sourceforge](http://quivi.sourceforge.net/), that I use to read manga and manhwa.  One of the options you can set is the "fit" of the image when its is opened.

From the documentation page

Viewing Tab
Fit: How the image is adjusted to screen when loaded.

Width: the width for the "Custom Width" fit option.

I don't use the scroll wheel to move up down in an image I tend to use the keyboard so I'm not sure how well the scroll wheel works.

It allows moving backwards and forwards within the folder of images and has the ability to move to the next/previous folder of images as well, useful for moving to the next chapter of a manga.